# UnrecognizedInputFormatException playing offline HLS

Tags: android, offline, playback, http-live-streaming, exoplayer

i am trying to playback offline dowloaded HLS. So, currently i have a dir with all the "xxx.v3.exo" chunks, and i followed this [guide](https://medium.com/google-exoplayer/downloading-streams-6d259eec7f95), but i have got this thrown exception:

```
com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.UnrecognizedInputFormatException: None of the available extractors (MatroskaExtractor, FragmentedMp4Extractor, Mp4Extractor, Mp3Extractor, AdtsExtractor, Ac3Extractor, TsExtractor, FlvExtractor, OggExtractor, PsExtractor, WavExtractor) could read the stream.
at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.ExtractorMediaPeriod$ExtractorHolder.selectExtractor(ExtractorMediaPeriod.java:820)
at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.ExtractorMediaPeriod$ExtractingLoadable.load(ExtractorMediaPeriod.java:742)
at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.Loader$LoadTask.run(Loader.java:315)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

I do not why it says that, becaused i have all the renderers properly setted, any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using MediaSource buildMediaSource function?

```
    simpleExoPlayerView.setPlayer(player);
    MediaSource mediaSource = buildMediaSource(Uri.parse(url));
    loopingSource = new LoopingMediaSource(mediaSource);
    player.prepare(loopingSource);

    private MediaSource buildMediaSource(Uri uri) {
     .....
    }
```